# Как из ссылки вытянуть мета теги?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как достать из ссылки название сайта, его описание итп. ?

Как это делают все эти большие соцсети ?

Comment: [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) может вытянуть конкретный элемент, или элементы

Comment: Но не с внешних страниц

Comment: что значит не с внешних страниц?

Comment: имею ввиду с чужих сайтов, не с моего сервера

Comment: Тут без разницы, это же обычный нет зарос

Answer (score 1):

Эти "большие соцсети" проверяют каждую ссылку и скачивают meta информацию по ней.

Вот, например, meta этой страницы

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />    
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=bc20db47c743&a" />
    <meta property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Как из ссылки вытянуть мета теги?" />
    <meta property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="Как достать из ссылки название сайта, его описание итп. ? Как это делают все эти большие соцсети ?" />
```

И если на указанной ссылке эти meta тэги не прописаны, то ничего путного "большие соцсети" со страницы не вытащат.

Это называется Open Graph Protocol.
Почитайте вот тут: http://ogp.me/

Comment: Ну ВК даже без опенграфа вытягивает некоторые данные из ссылки. Мне интересно, это доступно простым невежественным  смертным ?

Comment: ВК отгадывают... Парсят страницу и пытаются анализировать ее содержание. Большинство страниц, например, имеют правильный `<title>`... Простым смертным такое тоже по зубам. Вам надо почитать что такое `cURL` (http://php.net/curl). В двух словах: ваш код "заходит" на страницу, считывает ее source (это как view page source в браузере) и анализирует полученные данные. Ищет эти `meta` и их использует. Здесь, на RU.SO, много вопросов и ответов на эти темы.

Comment: Меня интересует, можно ли такое сделать на стороне клиента?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "стороной клиента"? Хотя по идее ничто не мешает делать ajax запросы, вытягивающие нужную информацию...